# Ruby on Rails Scaffolding development plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Is there any plugins in eclipse for Rails development. where i can design my own scaffolding template as we see in .Net MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two parts in your question.

**Firstly** you are looking for a eclipse plugin to work on rails. I would recommend [**Aptana Studio**](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) for that. Its just a customized version of eclipse and really handy for rails development. You will have console and other useful tools right on the spot.

**Secondly**, you want to customize your scaffold templates. Here are few links that might help. Though I didnt try this myself. You can share any specific difficulty while working on these.

- http://zigzag.github.com/2010/01/18/customizing-your-scaffold-template-become-easier-in-rails3.html
- http://spilth.org/notes/rails3-custom-scaffolding/
- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow

Did i miss any specific part of your question?

Comment: i already have aptana bt i still need something to edit the default view style nd controller as it is possible in .net mvc

Comment: Aptana is not an IDE. It's just a big software bug and nothing else.

Comment: @Green: ha ha ha... why are you saying so? my experience with Aptana is really good for ruby and php at least :) You can share the problems you have faced with it